# JavaScript mocked function returning undefined in tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, node-modules

I'm trying to test some JavaScript functions that are part of a larger React app. They make heavy use of the module pattern, which I suspect may be what I'm not understanding correctly. Here is the script I'm testing (nearly identical to the one actually used in the real app except that `GetFeedData.getFeedData` in the real one makes a call to an external API):

```
const GetFeedData = (function () {
let feed, feedId;
return {
    getFeedId: function (sub) {
        switch (sub) {
            case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case 'S':
                feedId = 1;
                break;
            case 'A': case 'C': case 'E':
                feedId = 26;
                break;
            case 'N': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'W':
                feedId = 16;
                break;
            case 'B': case 'D': case 'F': case 'M':
                feedId = 21;
                break;
            case 'L':
                feedId = 2;
                break;
            case 'G':
                feedId = 31;
                break;
            }
        },
        getFeedData: function () {
            if (feedId === 2) {
                feed = require('./MockData');
            }
        },
        feed: feed
    };
})();

const ReverseStop = (function () {
    let stopIdN, stopIdS;
    const stopData = require('../utils/stops');
    return {
        reverseStop: function (sub, stop) {
            var invalidEntries = 0;
            function filterByName (item) {
                if (item.stop_name == stop && typeof item.stop_id === 'string' && item.stop_id.charAt(0) == sub) {
                    return true;
                }
                invalidEntries ++;
                return false;
            }
            var stopObjs = stopData.filter(filterByName);
            for (var i = 0; i < stopObjs.length; i++) {
                if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'N') {
                    stopIdN = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
                } else if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'S') {
                    stopIdS = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
                }
            }
        },
        stopIdN: stopIdN,
        stopIdS: stopIdS
    };
})();

export const IsDelayN = (function () {
    let noDelay, yesDelay, nextArrival, delay;
    return {
        isDelay: function (sub, stop) {
            GetFeedData.getFeedId(sub);
            GetFeedData.getFeedData();
            ReverseStop.reverseStop(sub, stop);
            var arrivals = [];
            var delays = [];
            function dataFilter () {
                var invalidEntries = 0;
                var feedObjs = GetFeedData.feed.filter(function (feedObj) {
                    if (feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == ReverseStop.stopIdN) {
                        return feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                    }
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs.length; i++) {
                    arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                    delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
                }
            }
            nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
            var delayIndex = arrivals.indexOf(nextArrival);
            delay = delays.delayIndex;
            if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
                noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - GetFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
            } else {
                yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
            }
        },
        noDelay: noDelay,
        yesDelay: yesDelay,
        nextArrival: nextArrival 
    };
})();

export const IsDelayS = (function () {
    let noDelay, yesDelay, nextArrival, delay;
    return {
        isDelay: function (sub, stop) {
            GetFeedData.getFeedId(sub);
            GetFeedData.getFeedData();
            ReverseStop.reverseStop(sub, stop);
            var arrivals = [];
            var delays = [];
            function dataFilter () {
                var invalidEntries = 0;
                var feedObjs = GetFeedData.feed.filter(function (feedObj) {
                    if (feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == ReverseStop.stopIdS) {
                        return feedObj.entity.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                    }
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs; i++) {
                    arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                    delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
                }
            }
            nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
            var delayIndex = arrivals.indexOf(nextArrival);
            delay = delays.delayIndex;
            if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
                noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - GetFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
            } else {
                yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
            }
        },
        noDelay: noDelay,
        yesDelay: yesDelay,
        nextArrival: nextArrival
    };
})();
```

What I'm attempting to do is separate out my functions so I have several shorter ones I can call in the exported functions, rather than one or two extremely long functions. Because I need to call a couple variables - `GetFeedData.feed`, `ReverseStop.stopIdN`, and `ReverseStop.stopIdS` in the exported functions, I am assuming that the module pattern is a better way to go than using callbacks. I could totally be wrong.

In my tests, I try log `noDelay`, `nextArrival`, and `delay` to the console to see if they are defined. I'm using Jest, if that information is helpful. I'll omit the other parts of my test for now because they don't seem relevant (please correct me if that's wrong), but here is that section:

```
it('correctly takes input at beginning of api logic and outputs expected values at end', () => {
    IsDelayN.isDelay('L', 'Lorimer St');
    IsDelayS.isDelay('L', 'Lorimer St');

    expect(IsDelayN.noDelay).toBeTruthy();
    expect(IsDelayN.yesDelay).toBeFalsy();
    expect(IsDelayS.noDelay).toBeTruthy();
    expect(IsDelayS.yesDelay).toBeFalsy();
    console.log('IsDelayN noDelay: ' + IsDelayN.noDelay);
    console.log('IsDelayN nextArrival: ' + IsDelayN.nextArrival);
    console.log('IsDelayN delay: ' + IsDelayN.delay);
    console.log('IsDelayS noDelay: ' + IsDelayS.noDelay);
    console.log('IsDelayS nextArrival: ' + IsDelayS.nextArrival);
    console.log('IsDelayS delay: ' + IsDelayS.delay);
});
```

The tests prior to my `console.log()`s are all passing, but every `console.log()` is turning up `undefined`. Also, the script that's actually being called by my React components is coming up with the same results. I have my component set to render `null` if these variables aren't defined, and that's exactly what's happening.

Any help with understanding this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not set the modules correctly, when setting a member value you should mutate the object, now you just set a variable value.

The following should work for you:

```js
    var module = (function(){
      const ret = {
        mutateSomething:function(value){
          //set otherValue on the object returned (mutate ret)
          ret.otherValue = value;
        }
        ,otherValue:undefined
      };//create the object first
      return ret;//then return the object
    }())//IIFE

    console.log("before mutate:",module.otherValue);
    module.mutateSomething("Hello World");
    console.log("after mutate:",module.otherValue);
```